# Program stopps working at GetMessage() function

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I'm pretty new to the Hook-Stuff and I'm trying to learn how to work with it. When I learn new stuff I usually copy Code from the Internet and see if it works - if yes i go into detail and search everything up. So with all Codes I tried I have the same issue. They stop working at the `GetMessage()` function. I'm working with Visual Studio - I debugged it and when it reaches the function it just does nothing but stays on it.
I tried it with several Codes - for example this one:

```
    HMODULE lib = LoadLibrary("C:\\Users\\A\\Desktop\\Dll1.dll");
if (lib) {
    HOOKPROC procedure = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(lib, "_procedure@12");
    if (procedure)
        hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, procedure, lib, 0);
    else
        printf("Can't find function in dll!\n");
}
else
    printf("Can't find dll!\n");
if (hook)
    printf("Hook installed properly!\n\n");
MSG message;
while (GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&message);
    DispatchMessage(&message);
}

FreeLibrary(lib);
UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook);
```

It prints "Hook installed properly!" and does nothing! The code is from http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/41238-global-hooks-to-intercept-windows-messages/

Comment: `GetMessage` is a blocking call. Why did you not expect it to block?

Comment: *They stop working at the GetMessage() function.* - what you mean under this ?

Comment: To downvoters: Yes, the question is a little untidy and the code perhaps not quite minimal, but fundamentally this seems to be a genuine, answerable question. A good answer would say that GetMessage is a blocking call, explain what that means, and describe how to send some messages that might unblock it. This does seem useful to future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike a mouse/keyboard hook, a window procedure hook runs in the context of a hooked thread that calls a window procedure.  It does not delegate back to the thread that installed the hook, like you are expecting.  That is why a window procedure hook must exist in a DLL when hooking other processes - the DLL gets injected into the address space of a hooked process, and then the hook is called by any hooked thread before/after it passes a message to a window procedure.

Your program that is installing the hook has no windows of its own, so no messages are being received.  That is why `GetMessage()` blocks your app indefinitely.  You would need to add a UI to your app, or have your hook manually post/send its own message back to your app using `(Post|Send)Message()` or `PostThreadMessage()`, in order to unblock `GetMessage()`.

Comment: Yes exactly, the op is ignoring the context of which get/dispatchmessage is used for, there must be a windows gui for the loop to work upon.

Comment: Thanks alot! I didnt find anything about that on the internet, I don't know why my question gets downvoted..

Comment: @xlfastxikex: likely due to lack of research, as the information is out there

Comment: I know i run off the topic but what is this forum for if not for asking questions where I didn't find an answer for? Searching for "PostThreadMessage" you're right there are tons of results but i can't search for something i don't even know. You can try to google "GetMessage freezing" or even "GetMessage block", there is nothing ..

Answer (score 0):

Your program is not going to receive messages unless it creates windows, hooks are delivered as part of the hooked program's message loop (that is why the hook function needs to be in a DLL for this situation).

The message queue is specific to the thread that created the window, posted messages are always going to be received on the thread that created the window, that is simply the way Windows operates.

Comment: Probably right, but the question does not have enough context to be sure. Side note: You don't need to have a window. You can `PostThreadMessage` your own messages.

Comment: It probably answers my question, but what do you mean with PostThreadMessage ?

Comment: Message queues are associated with threads, not windows. Every thread creates a message queue the first time it calls a USER32 function. It need not have a window.